# Has anyone tried using typescript enums in AngularJS HTML pages?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

In Typescript I created an enum like this:

```
enum Action { None = 0, Registering = 1, Authenticating = 2 };
```

In my controller I set a property called action like this:

```
class AuthService implements IAuthService {

    action: number;

    constructor(
        private $state,
        private userService,
        private utilityService: IUtilityService
        ) {

        this.action = Action.None;

    }

    doRegister() => {
       this.action = Action.Registering;
    }
```

This works good but how can I use the enum in my HTML. Is that possible? What I would like to do is to use it in some place like this:

```html
<span ng-class="{'fa-spin fa-spinner': app.authService.authenticating }">
```

Without the need to create different variables for:

```
app.authService.authenticating
app.authService.registering
...
etc
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put that on the `$rootScope` e.g.

```
mainmodule.run([
    '$rootScope'
], function ($rootScope){

    // put it on $rootScope
    $rootScope.Action = Action;
});
```

And since every `$scope` inherits from it it is on each scope and you can just do `Action.foo` etc.

Note: For directives with an isolate scope you need to do `$root.Action.foo`. Just `Action` would not work as it intentionally breaks the prototype chain.

Comment: I've been doing some checking into the use of constants also. Do you think it's easier to use the app.constant( or use a Typescript solution?

Comment: Can you show me how I would inject $rootScope into the controller? Do I inject $rootScope or just $scope?

Comment: Both. But you don't need to. Use enums like any other ts utility function that doesn't need access to angular